# Log transformation not making data normal

Tags: regression, distributions, mixed-model, data-transformation, nonparametric

I have a data set with positive skewness  when I log tranform it tends to be negatively skewed.  Is there any other transformation that I can use or any statistical method works?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Cube root is often quite good for distributions near the gamma (Wilson-Hilferty); but in many situations you simply won't find a suitable transformation. More importantly, why do you need to make data normal?

Comment: Hello Glen_b, I am using linear mixed model for data analysis which assumes data to be normally distributed.  I could use generalized linear mixed model but I don't know the distribution.

Comment: (i) Are you looking at the marginal distribution of $y$? (ii) The discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) - by invoking Gauss Markov - seems to suggest you don't need to assume normality of even the errors to estimate the model (though the usual inference - hypotheses and tests - presumably relies on it in small samples).

Comment: Hello Glen_b, I guess I don't understand your point here about marginal distribution of y.  Are you referring to population averaged model that is estimated by generalized estimating equations? I know linear mixed model is one of regression model. I appreciate your clarification.

Comment: I mean "are you looking at the raw y's rather than conditional y's". So how did you decide "the data was skewed"? I'm reasonably sure there's no assumption - even for hypothesis tests - about the raw y's in linear mixed models.

Comment: Hello Glen_b, it was based on histogram and qq-plot.  What is conditional y?  I have one book about mixed model which mentions about normality assumption of residuals or y.

Comment: $y$ represents a mixture of values with different normal distributions. The vector of responses itself won't necessarily look normal.

Comment: Hello Glen_b, I know each y comes from normal distributions.  But that is how I was taught to check if the vectors of response meet the normality.  I am quite confused now what should I do now. Go with your suggestions or do transformation.

Comment: It depends what you did a histogram and QQ plot *of*. Consider a fixed effects one way ANOVA. Consider you have 4 groups, all with (population) sd 10. In group 1 the (population) mean is 100 (75% of the total population); in group 2 the mean is 121 (20%); in group 3 the mean is 142 (4.5%) and in group 4 the mean is 180 (0.5% of the total). Assume that your sample counts are proportional to the population proportions just mentioned. The normality assumption is true, but if you just plot the response without regard for the group its from  you get a quite skewed looking histogram or QQ plot.

Comment: Or consider an ordinary regression where $x$ is highly right skew but at each $x$ the $y$'s are normal. Then the normality assumption is satisfied but if you just take a histogram or QQ plot of $y$ you see skewness. If you do that, you're checking the wrong thing!

Comment: Thanks Glen_b.  I have a question related to mixed model.  we know the repeated measurements on single subject is correlated and dependent.  But when responses are conditioned on random effects, they are assumed to be independent.  What is intuitive logic or theory behind it?

Comment: I quite don't understand what you're asking. Are you saying 
"how can it be independent when you condition but dependent if you don't?"

Comment: Yes. I want to know the difference.

Comment: That's a whole new question to which my answer is too long for a comment (I know, I just tried). The explanation is quite similar to the issue with conditional normality but unconditional skewness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log is considered part of a whole continuum of power transformations...

```
Power  result
  -1   1/y
 -.5   1/sqrt(y)
   0   log y
  .5   sqrt(y)
   1   y
   2   y^2
```

(The $0$ case is confusing because we all know that $y^0=1$. But it works out if you look at the limit of $(y^p-1)/p$ as $p$ approaches zero.)

Anyway, note that $\sqrt y$ corresponds to $p=\frac12$ which is between the identity and the log -- so that might give you pretty good results.

Comment: Hello rvl, how is the interpretation after analysis with transnformed variable? can we interpret in terms of original scale of variable?

Comment: Well, you can square the mean to put it back on the original scale - it won't be the same as the mean, it's a different kind of mean. And you can back- transform confidence limits as well. But don't just back-transform the standard deviations or standard errors. Those will be wrong. (Look up the *delta method* if you want to know how to do this right.) finally, similar questions came up in another posting: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114259/does-the-average-of-the-square-roots-of-random-variables-mean-anything/114262#114262

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you need to get familiar with Box-Cox transformation that can be done via [this R package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/boxcox.html), among other things.